# Worker manager: not start work in enqueue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I have such code, I need to implement the task queue, if the task is in the queue, then you do not need to add it.
I implemented as shown in when, everything works, but sometimes the state of the worker remains ENQUEUED, and new tasks are not added to the queue.
That is, when there is no Internet, I add a task, when the Internet appears, tasks begin to run out, but for some reason, sometimes it doesn’t happen, I can’t understand why the task does not start despite the fact that the Internet is there and the task is in the queue.
How can you determine why the task will not start?
Does anyone have a better suggestion?

```
//run task
runOneTimeWorkByType<GetDocumentsWorker>(GET_DOCUMENTS_TAG)

     private inline fun <reified W : Worker> runOneTimeWorkByType(tag: String) {
            val workerInfoList = workManager
                .getWorkInfosByTag(tag)
                .get()

            for (item in workerInfoList) {
                if (item.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED){
                    return
                }
            }

            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

            val workRequest =
                OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<W>()
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .addTag(tag)
                    .build()

            workManager.enqueue(workRequest)
        }


        class GetDocumentsWorker(ctx: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
            Worker(ctx, workerParams) {
            @Inject
            lateinit var serviceUtils: ServiceUtils

            init {
                App.appComponent.inject(this)
            }

            override fun doWork(): Result {
                Log.d("workmng", "GetDocumentsWorker: start")
                try {
                    serviceUtils.documentsGet()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("workmng", "GetDocumentsWorker:  exception", e.cause)
                    return Result.retry()
                }
                Log.d("workmng", "GetDocumentsWorker: end")
                return Result.success()
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to start the task without conditions, but in this case, nothing starts either, have ideas why so?

```
fun runGetDocumentsTask() {
        val workRequest =
            OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<GetDocumentsWorker>()
                .addTag(GET_DOCUMENTS_TAG)
                .build()

        workManager.enqueue(workRequest)
    }
```

Everything starts to work fine when I cancel jobs: `workManager.cancelAllWork()`

When creating a worker, I run several periodic tasks, can there be a problem in them? If so, how to fix it?

```
private var workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(ctx)

    init {
        //workManager.cancelAllWork()
        runSendAllPeriodicTasks()
    }

    private fun runSendAllPeriodicTasks() {
        runOneTimeWorkOnPeriod<SendAllWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        runOneTimeWorkOnPeriod<FailureFilesResendWorker>(3, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        runOneTimeWorkOnPeriod<GetItemsWorker>(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    }
```